# Background color of link hover statusbar in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, colors, statusbar

I recently intalled the latest version of Chrome and noticed that the background color of the link hover status bar goes from black to lightgray everytime it is created.  Can this be changed so the background color stays lightgray all the time?

I find this color change thing really annoying.  I think this feature makes Chrome look a little like a cheap advertising site, like those with "*50% off*" flashing boxes.

Comment: Got it!!!  I am working on Windows Vista Business.  I installed Windows Vista Service Pack 1 and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

On which platform did you installed Chrome? Tested this on both Mac (10.9) and Win (7) with the latest version and the bar is always light grey, the color is not changing.

Regardless of the used platform I think there isn't a way to change this behavior. Maybe this is just a bug that will be solved in the next update. If not you should send an error report: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en